# Python-PDB automatically raise BdbQuit

Tags: python, shell

I have been using pdb.set_trace() to set some breakpoints in my codes, and always it was smooth.

I have a shell script that run a python script inside a loop:

```
cat $file1 | (
#read something from file1
while ... 
do
   if ... then
      cat $file2 | (
      # read something from file2
      while ...
          do 
               python test.py
               # read something from file2
          done)
   fi
   #read something from file1
done)
```

Assume that test.py is just a simple hello world. I put pdb.set_trace() in my python script. When I run the code outside the loop, simply by python test.py, everything is ok. However, when I execute the .sh script, the moment that it gets to the pdb.set_trace(), it raises a BdbQuit and quite my python script.

I could not realize what the problem is. I really appreciate if anyone can help me to figure this out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting *stdin* inside the `while` loop:

```
cat $file1 | while ...
```

The interactive pdb prompt reads from *stdin* as well, but since it's been redirected, it's just going to take input from that file.

The easiest solution in this case is just to use something like [remote-pdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remote-pdb), which opens up a network connection to which you can connect using e.g. `telnet` or `nc`.

Comment: Appreciate. I did not know that pdb also reads form stdin. very helpful note. I did not use remote-pdb, I just modified my code to at least be able to debug. Thank you.